# input attribute does not receive data

Tags: angular

I am trying to pass data to my component. Here is the code of component.

```
export class requestDetailComponent{
    @Input() id;
    @Input() name;
    @Input() email;
    @Input() purpose;
    @Input() programme;
    @Input() language;
    @Input() comments;

    visible = false;
    toggle() {
    this.visible = !this.visible;
  }
```

and the template is:

```
<div class="col-sm-5">    
    <label>{{name}}</label>
</div>
```

Here is the parent component which i pass the data

```
<ul>
      <li>
          <request-detail [name]='Salman'></request-detail>
      </li>
</ul>
```

I expect that the `Salman` appears in the child component, but it doesn't happen
what is the problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We should be aware that:

```typescript
name="Salman"
```

is just sugar for

```typescript
[name]="'Salman'"
```

So you can use both options.

See also [Angular 2 Template Syntax](https://vsavkin.com/angular-2-template-syntax-5f2ee9f13c6a#.r6y3uo4sb) by Victor Savkin

If you use the following syntax:

```typescript
[name]='Salman'
```

then you have to declare `Salman` variable in your component class:

```typescript
class ParentComponent {
  Salman = 'Salman'
}
```

Angular2 uses component instance scope to access variables in view.

If you don't have the `Salman` variable in your parent component then see picture below

[image]