# Angular 2 @Input number issue

Tags: angular, typescript, types

I have the following component:

```
<component value="3"></component>
```

And the component code is:

```
  private _value:number;

  get value(): number {
    return this._value;
  }

  @Input()
  set value(value: number) {
    console.log(value);
    console.log(typeof value);
    this._value = value;
  }
```

The log is:

```
3
string
```

But if I bind the property like:

```
<component [value]="variable1"></component>
```

In this case I get a number if variable1 is type number.

```
3
number
```

I know there's no magic with typescript but is this the right behavior? Should Angular Input decorator do the conversion?

I'm checking types in the setters, but I get errors when typescript is compiling.

I don't want to use type any in the gettes and setter.

Any elegant solution?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39817094/input-attribute-does-not-receive-data/39817212#39817212

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When binding with brackets `[]`, the value gets bound directly on the object.

With attribute binding, the value between the quotes gets handled as string.

[Maybe have a look at the docs.](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#binding-syntax)

---

> working [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/WIaTS7uenWubsP4S1OZO?p=preview) for example usage

Comment: I know all of this, the answer is not related with this.

Comment: That is how Angular 2 works - it even tells you in the docs. Without brackets (property binding) you don't bind to the actual variable, but just a string interpretation. What's your question then?

Comment: How to get always a type number in the input decorator?

Comment: With `[value]="3"`? http://plnkr.co/edit/WIaTS7uenWubsP4S1OZO?p=preview

Comment: Ok, sorry I didn't underestand what you really mean. Now I underestand everything