# Ionic 2 - Custom Component @Input not Working Correctly

Tags: angular, ionic2

I use Ionic 2 Rc2. I want to create custom navbar for all pages in my application. This navbar's title must change according to pages. I created navbar.ts and navbar.html . My application works with no error.

 if I use `<navbar [pageTitle]="1" ></navbar>` in home.html, pageTitle setted as 1. But if I use `<navbar [pageTitle]="home page" ></navbar>` in home.html, pageTitle's result undefined.

Navbar.ts

```
import { Component,Input } from '@angular/core';

import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'navbar',
  templateUrl: 'navbar.html'
})

export class CustomNavbar {

@Input() 
public pageTitle : string;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
        console.log(this.pageTitle);
  }

}
```

navbar.html

```
<ion-header>
   <ion-toolbar color="primary" no-border-bottom>
    <ion-buttons left>
      <button ion-button>
        <ion-icon name="contact"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-title  >{{pageTitle}}</ion-title>
    <ion-buttons right>
      <button ion-button>
        <ion-icon name="options"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
```

home.html

```
<navbar [pageTitle]="Home Page" ></navbar>

<ion-content padding>
welcome


</ion-content>
```

this case **pageTitle** returns undefined. Any Solution ? Thanks.

Comment: I think you are calling it inside constructor fn that's why it's value is undefined. call it inside ngOnInit(){}

Comment: is it undefined in rendered template or just in `console.log`?

Comment: console.log 's result undefined and Page title does not appear in rendered template

Comment: Angular binds inputs at `ngOnInit` function. If you `console.log` in `ngOnInit` function, you will be able to see the value. I made a research about `ion-title` element but couln't find anything. Are you sure that that element exists? If so please provide or check it's own documentation to see if providing input ot initialization is required or not.

Comment: @CanerBalım: this might help a little, I created a plunker using your code base (see src/app.ts and src/navbar.ts). Two things will emerge from that, logging the value in the constructor will return null even if everything is working as expected. Also it seems like the input isn't taking strings... no idea why, if you change "Home Page" to a numeric value it works. Here is the [example](https://plnkr.co/edit/rfNC7S?p=preview). I unfortunately don't know why it is only allowing numbers. Maybe someone else here knows why?

Comment: @DanSimon thanks for helping. I took same result. Is there any bug ?

Comment: @CanerBalım: I don't think there is a bug in Angular but I'm not sure why this is happening so it could be. I am going to review some code I have that does work and see if there is something different between the two. However, it will be a 4-5 hours before I can do that, weekend stuff keeping me busy.

Comment: @CanerBalım: So I took a look at my own code base and found that I am not using a string either, instead I am using an Array of strings(which really should be a service but meh). So to do some further testing with the [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/rfNC7S?p=preview) I found that numbers and Arrays work, no idea still why strings don't work. I would modify your question title to target that issue specifically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess it should be

```
<navbar [pageTitle]="'Home Page'"></navbar>
```

or

```
<navbar pageTitle="Home Page" ></navbar>
```

See also

- [input attribute does not receive data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39817094/input-attribute-does-not-receive-data/39817212#39817212)